# How do I cut down on this database's size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, database, compression

I have this huge database of information that I need to cut down on size as it's pretty big and very taxing to load up. What is the best way to go about 'zipping' this up and then expanding it using javascript?

Are there any tools that can do this for me? (Dean Edward's isn't packed enough, and gzip isn't available)

I'm looking for something that makes use of all the allowed javascript variables and looks for patterns (which there are many), similar to the way zip compression works.

Here's a sample of how my database is structured (the final result need to be in this format):

```
var crops =  {
Jan1: {
    Apple: [1995, 1996, 1998, 2003, 2007, 2008, 2009],
    Banana: [1995, 1998, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2007, 2008, 2009],
    Cantaloupe: [2000, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007],
    Date: [1995, 1998, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2007],
    Elephant: [1995, 2002, 2004, 2007, 2009],
    Fig: [1996, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007],
    Grape: [1999, 2000, 2001, 2004, 2006, 2008],
    Honeydew: [2001, 2005, 2008],
    Ita: [1997, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2004, 2005],
    Jasmine: [1997, 1998, 2002, 2004, 2005, 2007, 2008],
    Kiwi: [1997, 1998, 2003],
    Lemon: [1995, 1997, 2001, 2003, 2004, 2007, 2009],
    Melon: [1995, 1997, 2000, 2003, 2005],
    Nectarine: [1996, 1998, 2000, 2002, 2007],
    Orange: [1996, 1998, 2000, 2003, 2007],
    Pineapple: [1996, 1997, 1999, 2000, 2002, 2003, 2005, 2007, 2008, 2009],
    Quince: [1995, 1997, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2007, 2008],
    Raspberry: [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2007],
    Strawberry: [2002, 2003, 2006, 2008],
    Tangerine: [1995, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2006, 2008],
    Ugli: [1997, 2001, 2002, 2006, 2009],
    Vanilla: [1998, 1999, 2001, 2002, 2004, 2005],
    Watermelon: [1997, 1998, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2005],
    Xigua: [1996, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006],
    Yali: [1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2005, 2006, 2009],
    Zucchini: [2001, 2002]
},
Jan2: {
    Banana: [2005, 2009],
    Cantaloupe: [2006],
    Grape: [1997, 2005, 2006, 2007],
    Honeydew: [1999],
    Ita: [2001, 2002],
    Jasmine: [1999],
    Kiwi: [2008, 2009],
    Nectarine: [2001],
    Orange: [1997, 2008],
    Quince: [2005],
    Raspberry: [2002],
    Strawberry: [2004],
    Vanilla: [1995, 1999],
    Watermelon: [1997, 2002],
    Xigua: [2006, 2007],
    Yali: [2001, 2005],
    Zucchini: [2004]
},
Jan3: {
    Apple: [1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2009],
    Banana: [1997, 1998, 2001, 2006],
    Cantaloupe: [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2002, 2006, 2008],
    Date: [1995, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2005, 2007, 2008, 2009],
    Elephant: [1996, 1997, 1998, 2000, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007],
    Fig: [1998, 1999, 2000, 2002, 2003, 2009],
    Grape: [1997, 1998, 2002, 2005, 2006, 2007],
    Honeydew: [1995, 1996, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008],
    Ita: [1995, 1996, 2000, 2001, 2004, 2005, 2008, 2009],
    Jasmine: [1995, 1999, 2002, 2007, 2008],
    Kiwi: [1996, 2003, 2006, 2008, 2009],
    Lemon: [1995, 1996, 1999, 2002, 2006, 2007, 2009],
    Melon: [1997, 1999, 2002, 2005, 2008],
    Nectarine: [1998, 2000, 2002, 2004, 2005, 2008],
    Orange: [1995, 1997, 2000, 2002, 2005, 2007, 2009],
    Pineapple: [1998, 2001, 2002, 2004, 2005, 2007, 2009],
    Quince: [1995, 1997, 2000, 2002, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2009],
    Raspberry: [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 2002, 2004, 2007, 2008],
    Strawberry: [1996, 1997, 1999, 2000, 2006],
    Tangerine: [1999, 2001, 2004, 2007, 2008],
    Ugli: [1995, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2006, 2007, 2009],
    Vanilla: [1996, 1997, 2003, 2006, 2008],
    Watermelon: [1995, 1997, 1999, 2002, 2003, 2005],
    Xigua: [1996, 1997, 1999, 2001, 2004, 2006, 2008, 2009],
    Yali: [1996, 1998, 2001, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2007, 2008],
    Zucchini: [1997, 2003, 2006, 2007, 2009]
},
Jan4: {
    Apple: [2000, 2002, 2003],
    Cantaloupe: [2009],
    Elephant: [2003],
    Fig: [2001, 2008],
    Honeydew: [2001],
    Pineapple: [2004],
    Quince: [1999],
    Ugli: [2009],
    Vanilla: [2005],
    Yali: [2007]
},
Feb1: {
    Apple: [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2009],
    Banana: [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2008, 2009],
    Cantaloupe: [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009],
    Date: [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009],
    Elephant: [1996, 1997, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2009],
    Fig: [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009],
    Grape: [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009],
    Honeydew: [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009],
    Ita: [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2009],
    Jasmine: [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009],
    Kiwi: [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009],
    Lemon: [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009],
    Melon: [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009],
    Nectarine: [1995, 1996, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009],
    Orange: [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009],
    Pineapple: [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009],
    Quince: [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008],
    Raspberry: [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009],
    Strawberry: [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2009],
    Tangerine: [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008],
    Ugli: [1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009],
    Vanilla: [1995, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2007, 2008, 2009],
    Watermelon: [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2004, 2006, 2007, 2009],
    Xigua: [1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009],
    Yali: [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009],
    Zucchini: [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2009]
},
Feb2: {
    Apple: [1995, 1996, 1998, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009],
    Banana: [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2008, 2009],
    Cantaloupe: [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2001, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007],
    Date: [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2009],
    Elephant: [1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009],
    Fig: [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009],
    Grape: [1995, 1996, 1998, 1999, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009],
    Honeydew: [1995, 1996, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009],
    Ita: [1995, 1997, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009],
    Jasmine: [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008],
    Kiwi: [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2006, 2007, 2009],
    Lemon: [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008],
    Melon: [1995, 1996, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009],
    Nectarine: [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009],
    Orange: [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009],
    Pineapple: [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2009],
    Quince: [1995, 1996, 1997, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009],
    Raspberry: [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009],
    Strawberry: [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2009],
    Tangerine: [1996, 1997, 1998, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2008, 2009],
    Ugli: [1995, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2003, 2006, 2008, 2009],
    Vanilla: [1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2008],
    Watermelon: [1997, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2007, 2009],
    Xigua: [1995, 1996, 1997, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009],
    Yali: [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2003, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009],
    Zucchini: [1995, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2001, 2003, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009]
},
Feb3: {
    Apple: [1996, 1997, 2003, 2004],
    Banana: [1998],
    Cantaloupe: [1996, 1997, 1999, 2000],
    Date: [1996, 1997, 2006],
    Elephant: [2004],
    Fig: [1995, 1996, 2001, 2006, 2008],
    Grape: [2003],
    Honeydew: [2004],
    Ita: [1997, 2009],
    Jasmine: [1999, 2004, 2006, 2008],
    Kiwi: [1999, 2002, 2003, 2006],
    Lemon: [1995, 1997, 2004],
    Melon: [2008],
    Nectarine: [1995, 1998, 2005],
    Orange: [2003, 2009],
    Pineapple: [1995, 2001],
    Quince: [1995, 1996, 2000, 2004, 2005, 2006],
    Raspberry: [1996, 1999, 2000, 2003, 2009],
    Strawberry: [1995, 1998, 2001, 2004, 2008],
    Tangerine: [1996, 1998, 2002],
    Ugli: [2008],
    Vanilla: [1996, 2007, 2009],
    Watermelon: [2006, 2008],
    Xigua: [1998, 1999, 2002, 2005, 2009],
    Yali: [1996, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2004],
    Zucchini: [1998, 2000, 2003, 2007]
},
Feb4: {
    Apple: [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 2000, 2002, 2003, 2006, 2009],
    Banana: [1995, 1996, 1997, 2000, 2002, 2004, 2005, 2007, 2008, 2009],
    Cantaloupe: [1995, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2007, 2008],
    Date: [1995, 1997, 1998, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2004, 2005, 2008, 2009],
    Elephant: [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2003, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009],
    Fig: [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2005, 2007, 2008, 2009],
    Grape: [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 2003, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008],
    Honeydew: [1995, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2009],
    Ita: [1995, 1997, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009],
    Jasmine: [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2007, 2008, 2009],
    Kiwi: [1995, 1996, 1997, 1999, 2000, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2007, 2008],
    Lemon: [1995, 1996, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2003, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009],
    Melon: [1995, 1996, 1998, 2000, 2002, 2003, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008],
    Nectarine: [1996, 1997, 1998, 2000, 2003, 2004, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009],
    Orange: [1996, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2006, 2008],
    Pineapple: [1995, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2009],
    Quince: [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2002, 2004, 2005, 2007, 2009],
    Raspberry: [1997, 2002, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009],
    Strawberry: [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 2000, 2001, 2004, 2007, 2008],
    Tangerine: [1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008],
    Ugli: [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2001, 2003, 2007, 2008, 2009],
    Vanilla: [1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009],
    Watermelon: [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2001, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009],
    Xigua: [1996, 1997, 1998, 2000, 2003, 2005, 2007, 2008, 2009],
    Yali: [1995, 1997, 1998, 2005, 2007, 2008],
    Zucchini: [1995, 1996, 1997, 2000, 2003, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009]
},
Mar1: {
    Apple: [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009],
    Banana: [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009],
    Cantaloupe: [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009],
    Date: [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009],
    Elephant: [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009],
    Fig: [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009],
    Grape: [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009],
    Honeydew: [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009],
    Ita: [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009],
    Jasmine: [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009],
    Kiwi: [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009],
    Lemon: [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009],
    Melon: [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009],
    Nectarine: [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009],
    Orange: [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009],
    Pineapple: [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009],
    Quince: [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009],
    Raspberry: [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008],
    Strawberry: [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009],
    Tangerine: [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009],
    Ugli: [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009],
    Vanilla: [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009],
    Watermelon: [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009],
    Xigua: [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009],
    Yali: [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009],
    Zucchini: [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009]
}
/* Much much more */
}
```

Comment: If you serve the pages with gzip compression, won't that be good enough?

Comment: @Pointy: I wish but that's not an option

Comment: ?!?  Why isn't it an option?  What modern web server won't support gzip compression?  (Asking mostly out of curiosity ...)

Comment: Well you have my sympathies ... as far as I know it's been available for over 10 years with Apache.

Comment: You could manually gzip on the server and add the correct http headers.

Comment: What are you doing that requires so much data to be sent to the client, anyway? If you're doing a complex plot, do it on the server. If you've got cascading menus, use AJAX to load information only when it's needed. Basically, you should try to send to the client only information that it's *guaranteed* to need. Get anything else when it's asked for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compact your data. You have 12 months, (say) 20 fruits, and a range of years that, presumably, has a lower limit. Store the data like this:

```
{[1,[1,[1,2,4]],[2,[4,6,7]]],[2,[1,[4,5,6]]], ... }
```

Each array element is:

```
[month, [fruit, [year1, year2, year3,...]]]
```

If you need it in long form to deal with, you can convert it easily with a reference.

1 = Apple, 2= Banana, ...

1 = Jan, 2 = Feb, ...

1 = 1995, 2= 1996, ...

Answer (score 0):

You can store each combination of fruit, day and year as a single bit.
If you let Apple be bit 1, Banana bit 2 and so on you get 26 bits per day. You can store 26 bits in a 32 bit integer.
So every year takes up 365 integers (except leap years which are 366) or 1460 bytes.

That would be your data store. Then you can unpack individual (or all) days in javascript.

Comment: How would you propose that client-side JavaScript would receive and decode such a format?

Comment: Store it as arrays of integers and then unpack them as needed. Not sure if they can be transferred in binary form, so the transfer size may be bigger (10 bytes per integer in ascii form, + packaging).

Comment: Right - that's what I figured too, but I thought maybe you knew of some interesting trick :-)

Answer (score 0):

If the program is that too much data is transferred over the wire, then this would help a little: Subtract a standard value from the years and remove any unnecessary spaces. Here I have subtracted 2000 from the numbers.

```
// Before.
Jan1: {
    Apple: [1995, 1996, 1998, 2003, 2007, 2008, 2009],

// After.
Jan1:{Apple:[-5,-4,-2,3,7,8,9],
```

You can compress the data using inflate / gzip. This is supported by most browsers. The setup depends on your web server. Also: I am not sure if this is supported by XmlHttpRequest, the object that AJAX relies on.

Answer (score 0):

Alexei White had a blog-post (and proof-of-concept) on [online JS compression](http://blogs.nitobi.com/alexei/?p=166) (to make JS footprint smaller if cached on client-side). However his solution is still slow with an cutting-edge Chrome. I tried your sample-data and it locked the browser for ~5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Why does it have to be in Javascript?  Couldn't you put it on the server in a real database, and then expose the data via a service or OData so that the page could query it?

Comment: It needs to be in one file that's served with the page